# How is php-fpm socket folder ({/var,}/run/php-fpm) created on Linux?

Tags: linux, php, centos7, php-fpm

I am setting up multiple php versions on CentOS7 (native and from remi repos). As installed, the native php-fpm ( is setup on a unix socket, while the (remi) php74-php-fpm would listen on a TCP socket. I changed that by setting:

```
  listen = /run/php-fpm/php74.sock
  ...
  listen.owner = nobody
  listen.group = nobody
  listen.mode  = 0666
```

which is OK as long as both services are running. However if I stop both services, then start ONLY php74-php-fpm the socket folder (/run/php-fpm) is missing and the service fails. I looked in the obvious place (/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/*) for the folder creation, but it's not mentioned there.
I also inserted (via systemctl edit) the lines:

```
[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=php-fpm
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
```

in  php74-php-fpm.service, (the lines come from the native php-fpm) speculating that thhey would make systemd create the folder at startup, but it's not happening.

Hence the question - How do I force the folder creation when starting php74-php-fpm? I would rather not dick around with shell hacks and somesuch as I believe the native php-fpm is using a somewhat "standard" approach, which I would prefer.

TIA & cheers.

Comment: Do you have an explicit requirement that the sockets are in `/run/php-fpm` directory? I would just use `/run/php7.4.sock` as the socket entry. The creation of `php-fpm` directory in native package is likely an extra adjustment from the package maintainers, and would need to be ported to the remi packages separately.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen read the answer I posted below to see where I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that adding:

```
[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=php-fpm
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
```

does indeed force the creation of the /var/run/php-fpm folder, but this is needed **only** on Centos7.

And of course I messed up. I was changing a mix of CentOS8 machines (where the problem does not exist - bottom section explains why) and CentOS7 machines, ran systemctl edit on the CentOS7 machinines, then checked for the existence of /run/php-fpm on a CentOS8 machine (too many terminals).

What happens is, on **CentOS8** php-fpm is the default for apache, and the remi www.conf, as well as the supplied apache config php74-php-fpm.conf reflect that, setting the socket folder to /var/opt/remi/php74/run/php-fpm/ (a non volatile folder).

On **Centos7**, however, mod_php is the default, and remi apache configuration file makes no php-fpm provision (one has to set it up in the site config files). Following the native php-fpm config, I set the socket folder to /run/php-fpm, which is volatile and managed by systemd - making it necessary to change the php74-php-fpm service definition in order to create the folder at startup.

So it appears that there are multiple methods of managing volatile directories, which I think is confusing and error prone, as it appears people are using both with no discernible rationale. But what do I know.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278759/how-is-php-fpm-socket-folder-var-run-php-fpm-created-on-linux/76279335

Answer (score -2):

Install PHP by running command

```
sudo apt install php
```

Next, install php-fpm

```
sudo apt install php-fpm
```

php-fpm will be installed automatically. Check the location of the sock file by running the command

```
find / -name "*fpm.sock"
```