# How can I permanently change the ownership of /run/php?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php-fpm

On my Ubuntu server, I run Apache 2 with a *php8.2-fpm* pool, and I have changed the PHP user, which is not *www-data* anymore.

I've changed the `php-fpm.conf` (/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf), so that the user is my new user.

My problem is that every time the server gets rebooted, the folder `/run/php` always changes back to *www-data* ownership, so I have to manually *[chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown)* the folder to get PHP running as it should.

Where can I permanently change the ownership of this folder?

Comment: *Why* do you do this? You will probably have to update the systemd unit...

Comment: Almost answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1131404/how-is-php-fpm-socket-folder-var-run-php-fpm-created-on-linux

Comment: @vidarlo _"Why do you do this?"_ - Because running PHP and the webserver under the same user is a terrible idea for security.

Answer (score 2):

`/run` uses `tmpfs`, a volatile memory-only filesystem whose contents is lost when the system is rebooted. It's not possible to set anything "permanently" there. It's recreated anew during system boot and startup of services.

The directory is created by systemd according to the settings of the service unit. You need to adjust your unit for systemd to create a directory with correct permissions.

Run the editor to start an override file:

```
systemctl edit php8.2-fpm
```

It will open your default editor with the current state of the unit for reference. You need to add `User` and `Group` options (look at comments to see where to put this):

```
[Service]
User=youruser
Group=yourgroup
```

---

That said, better leave it running as www-data and add your user to the group of www-data as needed instead.

Comment: I have already changed the user and group in the php8.2-fpm service.
This server is only a development server, so there are some other reasons for having another user than www-data.